# Geth server syncs itself very slow on SSD storage

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, synchronization

This is the second time I've lunched a Geth server with full mode on a server with the resources below:

- 4Core CPU
- 16GB RAM
- 400GB SSD

But server keeps staying arount half of `highestBlock` and its synchronization is very slow. It's the second day that I'm checking this server and the current status is:

```
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 4185982,
  highestBlock: 10042734,
  knownStates: 0,
  pulledStates: 0,
  startingBlock: 0
}
```

May you tell me what is the problem? Aren't the resources enough? Or I had some other mistakes?
This is the command I used to run geth:

```
geth --rpc --rpcport 1555 --rpcapi personal,eth,web3,txpool,net
```

I also tested `--cache 8192` in this command, but nothing did not change.

Comment: Did you start synchronizing from empty? I just want to make sure you haven't tried other sync modes before this on the server

Comment: Yes. It was the only mode I have used